# Expanding $\boldsymbol \nabla\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ where $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{a},t)$

Tags: calculus

How does $\boldsymbol \nabla\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ expand where $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{a},t))$ and $\mathbf{x} =(x_1,x_2,x_3) $ and $\mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ where $\boldsymbol \nabla = (\partial_{a_1}, \partial_{a_2}, \partial_{a_3})$?

Here $x_1 = x_1(a_1)$ etc.

$$\boldsymbol \nabla \phi = (\partial_{a_1}, \partial_{a_2}, \partial_{a_3})\phi = (\partial_{a_1}\phi, \partial_{a_2}\phi, \partial_{a_3}\phi)$$

The first component: $$\partial_{a_1}\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial a_1}$$

but writing derivative wrt $\mathbf{x}$ is a little confusing for me.

Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: If this makes it clearer, we have $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)\equiv\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)$. Use the chain rule to this function that takes 4 arguments.
For example,
$$\partial_{a_1}\phi=\partial_t\phi\partial_{a_1}t+\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_{x_i}\phi\partial_{a_1}x_i$$

Comment: @Flewer47 You should write this as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer taken from my comment:

If this makes it clearer, we have $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)≡\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)$. Use the chain rule to this function that takes 4 arguments. For example,
$$\partial_{a_1}\phi=\partial_t ϕ\ \partial_{a_1}t+\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_{x_i}\phi\ \partial_{a_1}x_i$$

If only $x_1$ depends on $a_1$, then this expression simplifies into
$$\partial_{a_1}\phi=\partial_{x_1}\phi\ \partial_{a_1}x_1$$